# Alert view on UINavigationBar in iOS7?

Tags: ios, navigation

Is there any suitable custom view which I can put just above the navigation bar?

Usually I was using UIAlertView for giving any alert. But now I want an VIEW on navigation bar to show infront of Navigation bar and hide after 5 second.?

Is there any component of build-in feature?

Thanks

Comment: There is only way to show view on navigation bar is to show it using local notification.

Comment: No, its something like to show errors which we usually show on UIAlertView.

Answer (score 0):

**There is always a way --**

Through this you can easily show view over navbar or tabbbar whereever you need..

https://github.com/ecstasy2/toast-notifications-ios

https://github.com/filipstefansson/UINavigationBarAlert